# Wie kann man viele neue Wörter einprägen?

Tags: german-to-english, standard-german, northern-german

**before 2 years I learned some German language level until B2, but somehow I forgot all the vocabulary.**

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language S.E.. Thank you for your contribution. Please don't hesitate to take the [tour], and look around how this site works. You probably expect a better answer than just "repetition". To get that you may want to consider an [edit] to your question giving us more details on what you need to know, and how this would be specific to the German language.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of learning methods or tools that claim to be the best to learn a language or its vocabulary, but I don't think that there is the *one* method that is best for everyone.

Comment: Practice. The vocabulary will come back easily.

Comment: Thank you so much for best comment @Janka

Comment: To elaborate on Janka's answer: I would not refer to any special "methods" for memorizing or re-memorizing words (such as flash cards or whatever). They are useful, but only to a certain extent. The best and most effective "method" is using words: speak! read! write! sing! whatever... use! the language, and use it in communication with other humans. For example, statt deine Frage hier auf English zu stellen, könntest du sie auf Deutsch stellen (Fehler sind erlaubt!), und schon hast du deinen Wortschatz trainiert!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ich danke ihnen, habe ich ganz verstehen.was sie meinen.

Comment: The question "best way to remember words in ..." has nothing to do with German, it is a universal question concerning the learning of *any language*.